# Как найти площадь многоугольника по формуле Гаусса?

Tags: python, алгоритм, геометрия

Пытаюсь создать функцию Гаусса на python для расчёта площади n-го многоугольника, помогите создать данную функцию. Вот мои попытки создать её:

```
def func(x, y):
for i in range(1, n):
    s = (1/2)*abs(sum((x[i]*y[i+1])+(x[i]*y[1]))-sum((x[i+1]*y[i])-(x[1]*y[i])))
return s

f = open('st.txt')
n = sum(1 for line in open('st.txt'))
```

Вот исходный файл:

```
1 2
2 1
3 4
5 6
```

Comment: Пытаюсь реализовать это https://your-online.ru/math-calculators/_land-plot-area-coordinates/formula_gauss.png

Comment: Отступы исправьте в коде

Answer (score 2):

Возьмём удобную форму формулы Гаусса (shoelace) [отсюда](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html). В Python последний элемент списка можно использовать с индексом -1, что чуть упрощает дело.

```
from math import sin, cos, pi

def polygonArea(xlist, ylist):
    area = 0
    for i in range(len(xlist)):
        area += xlist[i-1] * ylist[i] - ylist[i-1] * xlist[i]
    return 0.5*abs(area)

#квадрат
print(polygonArea([0, 0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 2, 0]))

#невыпуклый многоугольник - звезда https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pentagram.html
#площадь 0.31072 совпадает с A_filled
print(polygonArea([cos(pi/2 + pi*i/5)*(0.526-0.325*(i%2)) for i in range(10)], 
                  [sin(pi/2 + pi*i/5)*(0.526-0.325*(i%2)) for i in range(10)]))
```

А если дан список точек, и без использования питоновской фишки с отрицательным индексом:

```
def polygonAreaPts(pts):
    area = 0
    last = len(pts) - 1
    for i in range(len(pts)):
        area += pts[last][0] * pts[i][1] - pts[last][1] * pts[i][0]
        last = i
    return 0.5*abs(area)
```